# MDETERM gives Err:502 on non-contiguous range of cells

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I have the following setup:

A 3x3 matrix in the cells A1:C3 and a 3x1 vector in D1:D3.

I would like to calculate the determinant of a new matrix formed by the 1st column of the original matrix, the vector and the 3rd column of the original matrix.

The formula I enter is:  `=MDETERM(A1:A3:D1:D3:C1:C3)`

I get Err:502, but the data I am using has a determinant, I have verified it by placing the cells onto a different sheet and calculated the determinant of the contiguous range.

If you need data to reproduce, use a 3x3 identity matrix (in the columns A, B, C), whose determinant is 1, and then replace the middle column by a 3x1 vector (column D, whose content is actually the same as the middle column of the identity matrix, thus the whole range results in a matrix whose determinant is known to be 1.)

[image]

New 3x3 matrix formed by the colums A, D, C (in this order).

[image]

Comment: @Raystafarian See the update, it does not really depend on the data, but on the fact that the range selection produces the error.

Comment: I am not trying to calculate =MDETERM(D1:D3) or =MDETERM(A1:D3).

Comment: Does it require a n by n matrix? Right now that's a 1x3 that won't calculate or a 4x3 that won't calculate. If you do use `A1:C3` it will work

Comment: I have added an image of the problem, it's pretty straightforward, I would like to select non-contiguous cells to form a range to calculate a determinant. The new range is a 3x3 matrix, essentially containing the same data as the A, B, C columns, just to show that the determinant exists and what value it has to produce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range syntax you're using doesn't do what you think it does. Consider the case where you have an identity matrix in `A1:C3`. The syntax `A1:A3:C1:C3:B1:B3` does not refer to the matrix in A1:C3 with the second and third column swapped. It simply refers to `A1:C3`. Excel or LibreOffice or whatever other spreadsheet program sees this range definition and just looks for the top-left and bottom-right corners of the range in all that mess. It doesn't take order into account. It's just defining a rectangular range.

You can check this by putting the identity matrix in `A1:C3` and the matrix with swapped second and third columns in `E1:G3`. Check the determinants.

```
=MDETERM(A1:C3)
```

returns 1.

```
=MDETERM(A1:A3:C1:C3:B1:B3)
```

also returns 1.

But

```
=MDETERM(E1:G3)
```

returns -1.

In your particular case where the ranges you're trying to shuffle aren't contiguous, the syntax `A1:A3:D1:D3:C1:C3` is read as `A1:D3`. This is not a square matrix, so `MDETERM` returns an error.

If you want to find the determinant of that noncontiguous range, you'll have to recreate the matrix somewhere else on the sheet.

Comment: OK, thank you, that was what I was anticipating.